# Ices2/Icecast error:

Tags: icecast

I installed Icecast2 and Ices2. I am trying to play an audio stream in the following manner:

```
/etc/ices2/ices-playlist.xml and 
/etc/icecast2/icecast.xml at -> http://pastie.org/5686666
```

I am getting this error when running ices2 using `ices2 /etc/ices2/ices-playlist.xml`

```
[2013-01-14  22:48:18] INFO playlist-builtin/playlist_read Currently playing "/etc/ices2/music/music.ogg"
[2013-01-14  22:48:21] EROR stream/ices_instance_stream Failed initial connect to localhost:4000 (Couldn't connect: No such file or directory)
[2013-01-14  22:48:21] DBUG reencode/reencode_clear Clearing reencoder
```

The complete list of steps are at http://www.ehow.com/how_5183447_make-radio-stream-ubuntu.html

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does it actually say `<URL>:4000`?  Or did you redact your server's address from the error message?

Comment: it gave http://localhost:4000 . But I was not able to post my question with that.

Comment: Ah, that must be the anti-spam thing for new users.  I've upvoted your question so you shouldn't have that problem again, and edited it in.  Now, if you run `netstat -l`, do you see the port open in a listening state when Icecast is running?

Comment: Thanks! I See this :netstat -l
tcp        0      0 *:4000                  *:*                  LISTEN

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you `ping localhost`, is the IP shown `127.0.0.1` or `::1`?  Perhaps Icecast is only listening on IPv4.

Comment: It is shown as 127.0.0.1  <br> $ ping localhost

64 bytes from localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.027 ms

Comment: Not that I don't believe you... but this doesn't make any sense.  You're saying that you've started the Icecast server, and it is indeed listening on port 4000.  If you go to that URL in a web browser, you see the Icecast page and what not?  Yet if you try to connect with Ices to 127.0.0.1:4000 it doesn't work?  This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The output above is for 'ping localhost' . What does that have to do with icecast on port 4000? Pls correct me if I am wrong. or are you referring to my previous comment ?

Comment: When you ran netstat, it showed that the server was listening on port 4000.

Comment: oh. yeah .I am wondering if it could be the location or configuration of ogg files. I checked their locations but they seem fine.